# How do I read the arguments from a formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have the following function:

> function MyFunction(A as string, Optional B as integer) as string

to call this function in cell A1:

> =MyFunction("Hello","15")

I want to access the arguments of this function from another routine by reading the contents of the cell at A1:

> Range("A1").Formula

This however returns the entire formula with arguments as a string as the formula was entered in the cell. Is there a way to easily extract the arguments ("Hello" and 15)?I am trying to avoid the clunky text manipulation route.

Comment: What do you mean by clunky text manipulation?  Does that include using functions such as search and replace?

Comment: Why do you need to access the arguments from another function?  I'm guessing there's a cleaner way to do this - like caching them in `MyFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your arguments are Ranges, you can use the `Precedents` property to get at the arguments.

If that's not the case, I'm afraid text manipulation is what you've got. If you're only trying to parse a particular function (instead of any function), it's not that bad.

```
Function MyFunc(ar1, ar2)

    MyFunc = 1

End Function

Public Sub ReadMyFunc(rng As Range)

    Dim vaArgs As Variant

    vaArgs = Split(Split(Left(rng.Formula, Len(rng.Formula) - 1), "MyFunc(")(1), ",")

    Debug.Print "First arg is: " & vaArgs(0) & vbNewLine & "Second arg is: " & vaArgs(1)

End Sub
```

The result from the immediate window

```
?activecell.Formula
=MyFunc(A1,"1")
readmyfunc activecell
First arg is: A1
Second arg is: "1"
```